# Unable to install mysqlnd driver on centos 6 digitalocean

Tags: mysqli, centos, digital-ocean

Hi I am trying ton install mysqlnd driver in centos but getting the following error.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.usonyx.net
 * extras: centos.usonyx.net
 * updates: centos.usonyx.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php5-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: This question/answer is probably useful here: http://serverfault.com/q/458524/162751

Comment: Yes I tried that solution but still no success.

Comment: Your output from above does *not* include the Remi repo. Are you sure you set it up correctly?

Comment: I am getting this error after setting up Remi repo Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.usonyx.net
 * extras: centos.usonyx.net
 * remi-test: mirrors.thzhost.com
 * updates: centos.usonyx.net
Setting up Install Process
No package php-mysqlnd available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: You were trying `php5-mysqlnd` originally and are now trying `php-mysqlnd`. Did that change for a reason? Does `yum search mysqlnd` output anything?

Comment: No I was trying the command because the same command with sudo installed mysqlnd in my local pc which has ubuntu os. But on centos no luck.